# Not getting expected ambiguity in view with two labels side by side

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm laying out two `UILabel` side by side, where I want the right label to take just the space it needs. Like this:

```
 ------------------------------ 
|[left label     ][right label]|
 ------------------------------
```

I'm using hugging and compression to accomplish that, and it works.

My surprise is that, when I remove hugging and compression configuration (i.e. leaving the default ones), `hasAmbiguousLayout` doesn't return `true`.

As expected, I get random results, like the right label taking more space than needed, or the left label taking all the space and leaving none for the right label.

Why is `hasAmbiguousLayout` not returning `true`?

I'm calling it from `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if view.hasAmbiguousLayout() {
        print("Layout is ambiguous!")
        view.exerciseAmbiguityInLayout()
    } else {
        print("Layout is not ambiguous") // I'm always getting this
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you changed the relation between two labels as >= or <= ????

Comment: In any case I use width relationship between the labels. With compression resistance and hugging I guess is enough. But without them there should be ambiguity.